# jQuery- Do we have something like "OnBeforeSomeEvent"?

Tags: jquery, events

Do we have any event like "onBeforeSomeEvent" in jQuery?

For Ex,

```
<input type='button' class='confirmdelete' onclick='delete();' value='DELETE' />
```

Now I want to show a custom dialog for confirmation. (I don't want to use default confirm method in JavaScript).

So I need something like,

```
$('.confirmdelete').onBeforeClick(function() {
     if(true) //I show the custom dialog here and check some conditions. 
        return true;
     return false;
});
```

The `onclick` event should fire if I get 'true' from the onbeforeclick event.

Sorry, If I am confusing. May be like `beforeActivate` in Accordion.

Comment: what exactly would OnBeforeClick do?

Comment: I would ask the confirmation with my own dialog. May be Yes or No buttons

Comment: What is the programming language you are using? Is your page having more than one delete button?

Comment: I am creating a list with delete button on each item dynamically using jQuery and I want to get a confirmation just before clicking the delete button to go ahead.

Comment: I understand that. Do you understand my question or not?

Comment: No... I don't understand.

Comment: What is the programming language you are using? Is your page having more than one delete button?

Comment: I said I am creating a list with delete button on each item. So it means there are many items and as each one has delete button, there are many delete buttons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29026/discussion-between-arulmr-and-pitchai-pazhani)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just wrap the delete()?

Put your validation on the onclick() event, and if it's true, delete it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [.mousedown()](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) might help you.

Comment: I would show a dialog first to ask confirmation. Will the mousedown event help?

Comment: I gave it a second thought and it will probably make more sense to give the answer @Dragos Bobolea suggested a try.

Answer (score 0):

Add unique `id` to your delete buttons.

Try using [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) functionality of jQuery and [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

```
$('.confirmdelete').click(function () {
    var cur_id = this.id;
    var buttons = '<div id="dialog' + cur_id + '" title="Confirm" align="center"><input type="button" value="Yes" id="yes' + cur_id + '" /><input type="button" value="No" id="no' + cur_id + '" /></div>'

    $(this).after(buttons);
    $("#dialog" + cur_id).dialog();

    $("#yes" + cur_id).click(function(){
        alert('true - ' + cur_id);
        //Write your delete code here
        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('close');
        $("#dialog" + cur_id).remove();
    });

    $("#no" + cur_id).click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('close');
        $("#dialog" + cur_id).remove();
    });
});
```

Replace the alert with your delete code in the commented section. Here is a example: <kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/ELwLp/2/)</kbd>

Comment: I would show a dialog first to ask confirmation onclick. Will the mouseover event help?

Comment: When do you want to show the dialog? Before clicking or after clicking?

Comment: It is on clicking. But the "delete()" method should be called if I return true(When I click "Yes" from the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you [jQuery delete confirmation box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310004/jquery-delete-confirmation-box)

There also first trigger the confirmation for delete and after that event is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' class='confirmdelete' value='DELETE' />
```

**JS**

```
$('.confirmdelete').click(function () {
    var del = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (del) {
        delete();  // Just call your "delete()" method here..
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't like to use confirm method.